# Independent UIView in UITableView

Tags: ios, view, tableview

I created an iPhone app where it came with the `UINavigationController` and `UITableView` predefined.

I want to add an `UIView` on the top of the screen but every time user scrolls tableView, my view also scrolls. Is there anyway to make the view independent from the tableView scroll?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `UITableViewController`, use `UIViewController` and add `UITableView` as a subview

Answer (score 0):

Create your view and set it as table header view of your table view.

```
UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:yourView];
```

It will not scroll with tableView but always remain on top of table view.